# Is there a Windows 10 desktop setting to not minimize full screen apps when a new app is launched

Tags: windows-10

I am running a Windows 10 desktop machine with multiple monitors and there is a really aggravating behavior I am seeing that I would like to change if possible.

The behavior I see is that if I have a Windows App (for example the plex app) running in full screen mode on another monitor and then launch a new app (desktop or windows app) the app that was running in full screen mode minimizes and in most cases stops playing.

This behavior does not occur if the running app is not in full screen mode.  I have checked my tablet settings and tablet mode is disabled (and grayed out).  I have also checked individual app settings for something that would change this behavior and have found nothing.  Is there some other setting in Windows 10 that controls this behavior on a desktop environment?